# Remove opencart home page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, opencart

i am in this condition:

```
www.domain.com/index.php
contains an installation of Wordpress
```

and

```
www.domain.com/shop/index.php
contains an installation of Opencart
```

I **need to remove** the www.domain.com/shop/index.php page **and redirect**, if someone goes there, to the wordpress homepage.

Which is the best and faster method to do that? Htaccess? Simple php script? And how i can do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful. Nearly all pages on an Opencart site use `index.php?route=xxx` by default and there are various ways (both inside and outside of a vanilla installation) to configure alternative URLs for the homepage.

The easiest way to ensure all hits on your Opencart homepage will redirect to Wordpress is to edit your `catalog/controller/common/home.php` file. Replace the contents with this:

```
<?php  
class ControllerCommonHome extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        header('Location: /'); // or header('Location: /index.php'); if you prefer
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe in the htaccess file in yur `shop` folder, add this near the top:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+shop/(?:index\/php|)(\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R]
```